# How to populate a text field with "N/A" if user does not fill it in (Survey123 Connect)

Tags: arcgis-survey123, arcgis-survey123-connect

I have an "Additional Comments" field in a survey that I would like to display "N/A" in if left blank. This way when we generate the Reports, it will say "N/A" instead of being blank.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about a default value of "N/A" on the field. That way, if they don't fill it in, it will always have "N/A".

I also found an article, [Text field to record default answer if left blank](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/text-field-to-record-default-answer-if-left-blank/td-p/1144291), on the Esri Community. There, they recommend setting the value of

```
body::esri:visible
```

to be something like:

```
if(string-length(${textfield})=0,'text',.)
```

You could also look at [Webhooks for Survey123](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/browser/create-surveys/webhooks.htm). There, they describe creating a webhook which will trigger a service such as Microsoft PowerAutomate, Make, or Zapier. However, if you have access to FME Server, a webhook could be created there as well. You could have an FME workspace initiate that could update records based on field values. Might be a bit of overkill for something that could be accomplished with a default field value...

Answer (score 0):

Just enter "N/A" in the "default" column of your spreadsheet.